# What is the best practice to manually backup Autonomous Database?

Tags: database-backups, oracle-autonomous-db

What best practice shall one follow to create a backup or replication policy that can live longer than the 60 days retention for Autonomous Database (Shared)?

Answer (score 0):

The current retention for automated and manual backups on Autonomous Database (Shared) is 60 days.

You can use Data Pump Export for archival purposes or “backups” for longer than 60 days.

*Ref - I am a product manager on the Oracle Autonomous Database.*